# python program not completing execution

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone please help explain why this program does not complete executing. It leaves at array size printing and freezes the PC. I am plotting a PSF convolution. The preceding code doesn't have issues. My execution does not move to the print ('ready for fft')

````
def mono_PSF(self, wavelength, dioptres_def, dioptres_ob_ast, dioptres_ver_ast):
        print (wavelength)        
        r_per_logMAR = wavelength / (self.pupil_diameter * self.alpha)        
        d_per_logMAR = r_per_logMAR * 180 / math.pi        
        print ("d_per_logMAR: ", d_per_logMAR)        
        if d_per_logMAR > self.final_d_per_logMAR:            
            print ("Error: d_per_logMAR is too large (Landolt_C.py)")            
            raise SystemExit()        
        b_array_size = np.array([int(np.rint(self.alpha * self.array_size[0])), int(np.rint(self.alpha * self.array_size[1]))])        
        print("b_array_size: ", b_array_size)        
        wavefront = self.apply_defocus(dioptres_def) + self.apply_ob_astigmatism(dioptres_ob_ast) + self.apply_ver_astigmatism(dioptres_ver_ast)        
        # plt.figure()        
        # plt.imshow(wavefront)        
        # plt.show()        
        theta = wavefront * (2 * math.pi) / (wavelength)        
        # border the array of theta        
        b_theta = np.zeros((b_array_size))        
        # print theta.shape        
        # print b_theta.shape
        # print b_theta[0:self.array_size[0], 0:self.array_size[1]].shape        
        b_theta[0:self.array_size[0], 0:self.array_size[1]] = theta        
        dist = scipy.exp(1j * b_theta)        
        # border the aperture array        
        b_aperture = np.zeros((b_array_size))        
        b_aperture[0:self.array_size[0], 0:self.array_size[1]] = self.pupil        
        cw = b_aperture * dist        
        print ('ready for fft')        
        fourier_transform = np.fft.fft2(cw)        
        psf = np.abs(fourier_transform) ** 2  
        # take the modulus of the fft        
        psf = np.fft.fftshift(psf)  
        # shift the 4 quadrants        
        psf = psf / np.sum(psf)  
        # normalise the PSF to have a sum of 1        
        print('PSF generated')        
        return psf, b_array_size, d_per_logMAR   ```
````

Comment: At first you could add more "print"s to see exactly which line causes the problem. Alternatively you can use a debugger.

Comment: If it freezes the computer without yielding any error, you could consider testing it on smaller input to make sure it does what you want. Then optimize it if it is too slow for your use case.